# How to sort array of NumPy subarrays based on white pixel count in every subarray?

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

```
  img = np.asarray(Image.open("testtwo.tif").convert('L'))# reading and converting    image                         
  img = 1 * (img < 127)

   arraysplit = np.split(img.ravel(), 24) # here we are splitting converted to 1D array
```

How to get array with subarrays inside containing number of white pixels in some order?

Comment: You have asked [very similar questions six times already](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1101793/kvasdub?tab=questions), but you have never accepted an answer. Please accept an answer and stop posting the same question again and again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `key` keyword argument to `sorted` to accomplish this :

```
arraysplit = np.split(img.ravel(), 24)

splits_by_white_count = sorted(arraysplit, key=lambda a: (a == 256).sum())
```

Then `splits_by_white_count` will be a list of the splits of your image data, ordered by increasing count of white pixels (assuming you have 8-bit image data).

If you'd just like a list of the white pixel counts, in order, you could sort Christian's solution :

```
white_counts = sorted((a == 256).sum() for a in arraysplit)
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of zeros in the subarrays you could do this:

```
zeros = [(q==0).sum() for q in arraysplit]
```